# Different selection colors for different divs/spans on a webpage

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a Chrome plugin that allows users to select text on a news website and click on a `Share` button to send that information to a server. I have a color that is applied when the users selects text from the story. When the button is clicked, the plugin identifies if the number of characters selected exceeds 280. If it does, a warning message is shown and at the same time, the overflowing text is supposed to get selected with a different color. The latter is not happening.
Here's the code in content script:

```
var article_selected_text = window.getSelection().toString();
if (length > 280) {
  sel = window.getSelection();
  if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  }
  document.designMode = "on";

  var overflowRange = document.createRange();
  overflowRange.setStart(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset + 280);
  overflowRange.setEnd(sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset);
  var newNode = document.createElement("span");
  newNode.setAttribute('class', 'overflow-selection');
  overflowRange.surroundContents(newNode);
  
  document.designMode = "off";
}
```

Here's the CSS for selection:

```
::selection {
  background: #E2F4D3;
} 
.overflow-selection::selection {
  background: #E5E5E5;
}
```

The selection color for the `overflowRange` is not immediately visible when the button is clicked. However, if the same text is selected again, text upto 280 characters is selected in `#E2F4D3` and the rest is selected in `#E5E5E5`. For the sake of brevity, assume that only one paragraph or less is selected at one time.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a separate jsfiddle? If so, add it using the built-in snippet when editing the question. So far, without inspecting the result myself, I'd say it sounds like a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/bhghosh/9a4hcsy2/6/
It's not a perfect replication, but the relevant bits are there

Comment: Ah, evidently the new element is not a part of the current selection. It's either a bug or the intended behavior per some specification. Either way, you can try extending the selection to include that element e.g. getSelection().extend(.....) or something.

Comment: .extend() worked. Thanks!